# AJAX/JQuery Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have tried many solutions; I've debugged with FireBug and the error makes no sense.  I have other pages I've made similar to this that work perfectly.  The headers are being sent correctly, and the response that is displayed in FireBug is actually the correct response text; but it just doesn't display it on the page!  Instead it returns "Internal Server Error 500" and I don't understand why.

Here are my pages:

First one is my class page that handles new page creation, just so you could see how the javascript scripts are referenced:

```
<?php

// Page Class

class Page {

    public $title;

    function __construct ( $pageTitle = '', $scripts = "" )
    {
        global $config;

        if ( strlen ( $pageTitle ) > 0 )
        {
            $this->title = $config['site']['name'] . ' &raquo; ' . $pageTitle;
            $usePTitle = 1;
        } else {
            $this->title = $config['site']['name'];
            $usePTitle = 0;
        }

        echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">' . "\n",
             '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">' . "\n",
             '<head>' . "\n",
             '  <title>' . $this->title . '</title>' . "\n",
             '  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />' . "\n",
             '  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>' . "\n",
             '  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/functions.js"></script>' . "\n";

        if ( strlen ( $scripts ) > 0 )
        {
            echo '  <script type="text/javascript">' . "\n",
                 '  <!--' . "\n";

            include 'scripts/' . $scripts;

            echo '  //-->' . "\n",
                 '  </script>' . "\n";
        }

        echo '</head>' . "\n",
             '<body>' . "\n",
             '  <h2>' . ( $usePTitle == 1 ? $pageTitle : $config['site']['name'] ) . '</h2>' . "\n",
             '<hr class="nv" />' . "\n",
             $this->head();
    }

    function head ( )
    {
        global $user, $sql, $config;

        if ( $user->auth == true )
        {
            $pmc = $sql->result ( $sql->query ( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `private_msgs` WHERE `pm_user` = ' . intval ( $user->info['id'] ) ) );
            $headLinks = array ( 'Control Panel'                        =>      'user.php',
                                 'Private Messages (' . $pmc . ')'      =>      'messages.php',
                                 'Logout'                               =>      'logout.php',
                                 'Contact Us'                           =>      'contact.php'
                                 );
            echo '  <div id="userbar">' . "\n",
                        $user->info('name') . ' (' . $user->info('level') . ') ' . "\n",
                 '      <ul id="userlinks">' . "\n";
            foreach ( $headLinks as $t => $l )
            {
                echo '          <li><a href="' . $l . '">' . $t . '</a></li>' . "\n";
            }

            echo '      </ul>' . "\n",
                 '  </div>' . "\n",
                 '<hr class="nv" />' . "\n";
        } else {
            $headLinks = array ( 'Register'     =>  'register.php',
                                 'Login'        =>  'login.php',
                                 'Contact Us'   =>  'contact.php'
                                 );
            echo '  <div id="userbar">' . "\n",
                 '      Guest (' . $config['levels']['guest'] . ') ' . "\n",
                 '      <ul id="userlinks">' . "\n";
            foreach ( $headLinks as $t => $l )
            {
                echo '          <li><a href="' . $l . '">' . $t . '</a></li>' . "\n";
            }

            echo '      </ul>' . "\n",
                 '  </div>' . "\n",
                 '<hr class="nv" />' . "\n";
        }
    }

    function restrict ( $lvl )
    {
        global $user;

        if ( $user->info('level') < $lvl )
        {
            echo '  <h2>Authorization Error</h2>' . "\n",
                 '  <div class="text">' . "\n",
                 '      You are not authorized to view this page.' . "\n",
                 '  </div>' . "\n",
                 '<hr class="nv" />' . "\n";

            $page->genFooter(1);
        }

    }

    function genFooter ( $die = 0 )
    {
        $year = date ( 'Y', time() );
        $copy = '';

        echo '  <div id="footer">' . "\n",
             '      &copy;' . $year . ' ' . $copy . "\n",
             '  </div>' . "\n",
             '</body>' . "\n",
             '</html>';

        if ( $die == 1 )
            die();

    }

}

?>
```

The next page is my actual login.php page that the logins are supposed to be run with:

```
<?php

require 'inc.common.php';
$page = new Page ( 'Login', 'login.js' );

?>
<div id="content">
    <div id="result" class="result"></div>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <div class="text">
    <fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Username</legend>
            <input type="text" id="un" value="" size="20" /> <span id="un_error" class="error">*</span>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Password</legend>
            <input type="password" id="pw" value="" size="30" /> <span id="pw_error" class="error">*</span>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The next page is my "login.js" page that contains the JavaScript/AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#login").click(function() {

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Validating login...';

    var user = $("#un").val();
    var pass = $("#pw").val();

    if ( user == "" )
    {
        document.getElementById("un_error").style.visibility = 'visible';
        $("#un").focus();
    }

    if ( pass == "" )
    {
        document.getElementById("pw_error").style.visibility = 'visible';
        $("#pw").focus();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://stjohnspikapp.org/ajaxforums/login-parse.php",
        data: "un=" + user + "&pw=" + pass + "&session=" + Math.random(),
        success: function(msg) { document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = msg; }
    });

});
```

});

The final page is the login-parse.php page which is what receives the AJAX request and sends a response...

```
<?php

require 'inc.common.php';

$uname = $_POST['un'];
$pword = $_POST['pw'];

$errors = array();

if (! strlen($uname) )
    $errors[] = 'Invalid username.';

if (! strlen($pword) )
    $errors[] = 'Invalid password.';

$check = $sql->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = \'' . $sql->escape($uname) . '\' AND `user_password` = \'' . $sql->escape(md5($pword)) . '\'' );
if ( $sql->num_rows ( $check ) == 0 )
    $errors[] = 'Invalid username/password combination.';

/*if ( count ( $errors ) > 0 )
{
    echo '<blockquote>The following errors occurred while processing your request:' . "\n",
         '<ul>' . "\n";

    foreach ( $errors as $enum => $e )
    {
        echo '  <li><strong>(#' . ($enum+1) . '):</strong> ' . $e . '</li>' . "\n";
    }

    echo '</ul>' . "\n",
         '</blockquote>' . "\n";*/

if ( count ( $errors ) > 0 )
{
    echo '<blockquote>There was an error with your submission.</blockquote>' . "\n";

} else {
    setcookie ( 'ajax_un', $uname, time()+60*3600 );
    setcookie ( 'ajax_pw', $pword, time()+60*3600 );

    echo '<blockquote>' . "\n",
         '  You have been logged in successfully!<br />' . "\n",
         '  You may now return to the <a href="index.php">board index</a>.' . "\n",
         '</blockquote>' . "\n";
}


?>
```

Comment: Internal Server Errors (error #500) are logged in the server error log. Check your log and post the most recent error, and somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: @pattyd I could open a support ticket with my web host but I don't have access to the server error logs due to the hosting company.

Comment: What company is it? I am sure I could help you out.

Comment: @pattyd Bihira is the hosting company

Comment: Try turning php error reporting on in `login-parse.php`. Put `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top. This will then post the error message into Firebug. Just make sure to remove it when done debuggin.

Comment: @Sean I fixed it!  Thanks for the help man.  I tried doing that before and realized I typed "E|ALL" instead of "E_ALL".  Hehe

Comment: Glad to help. So what was the issue?

Comment: Simple syntax error in one of my class files; I forgot to globalize $sql in a function.  Silly me.

Comment: @user2555004 I'm glad you figured it out! I was going to suggest changing the error reporting, but was unsure how to do it dynamically. Congrats! +1